# WSDL-SOAP Webservice on PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have created php file. It contains details about to access (wsdl)xml file and function. I need to call a function with paramaters but i can't able to call a function. So, I have been given a WSDL file and I need to create a SOAP service for it in PHP. Could any one tell me what the correct way of doing it is?

Here is link of the WSDL: http://178.211.55.56/se/ws/wf_ws.php?wsdl
 and 
Here is my php code:

```
require_once 'lib/nusoap.php';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$soapclient = new nusoap_client("http://178.211.55.56/se/ws/wf_ws.php?wsdl",'wsdl');

$soapclient->setHTTPProxy("soap:address_location",8080,"usr_name","pwd");
```

when run above the php code return this error:

> wsdl error: Getting "WSDL link" - HTTP ERROR: Couldn't open socket
>   connection to server "WSDL link" prior to connect().  This is often a
>   problem looking up the host name.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

All you need is:

1. Create SOAP client:

`$client = new SoapClient("http://178.211.55.56/se/ws/wf_ws.php?wsdl");`

You can pass many options to the constructor, such as proxy, cache settings, etc.
Some examples for you:

`$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));`

`$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", ['login' => "some_name", 'password'=> "some_password"]);`

`$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", ['proxy_host' => "localhost", 'proxy_port' => 8080]);`

If ssl certificate is wrong you can ignore it. Example is here: https://gist.github.com/akalongman/56484900eaf19b18cfbd

2. Call one of the service defined functions:

`$result = $client->getResult(['param_name' => 'param_value']);`

Pay attention that your service function may have required parameters. Usually it can be found in the result message.

Comment: ok, but that web service need https to username and password, also try to this link in my used wsdl page: https://178.211.55.56/softexpert/webserviceproxy/se/ws/wf_ws.php for this request my sets: $soapclient->setHTTPProxy("https://178.211.55.56/softexpert/webserviceproxy/se/ws/wf_ws.php",8080,"usr_name","pwd"); but not working, result error is: wsdl error: Getting "WSDL link" - HTTP ERROR: Couldn't open socket connection to server "WSDL link" prior to connect(). This is often a problem looking up the host name.

Comment: If you need to pass username and pass you can do this: